# n_neighbor parameter of Local Outlier Factor affects to ROC-AUC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, anomaly-detection

I am trying to solve the outlier detection problem with several algorithms. When I use Local Outlier Factor API of Scikit-learn, I have to input a very important parameter--`n_neighbors`. However, with different `n_neighbors`, I receive different `ROC_AUC` scores. For example, with `n_neighbors=5` then `ROC_AUC=56`. However, with `n_neighbors=6` then `ROC_AUC=85`; with `n_neighbors=7` then `ROC_AUC=94`, etc. Formally, `ROC_AUC` is very high if `n_neighbors>=6`

I want to ask three questions:
(1) Why the `n_neighbors` parameter of Local Outlier Factor affects to ROC-AUC?
(2) How to choose an appropriate `n_neighbors` in an unsupervised learning setting?
(3) Should I choose high `n_neighbors` to get a high `ROC_AUC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the results would not be affected, the parameter would not be needed, right?

Considering more neighbors is more costly. But it also means more data is used, so I'm not surprised that results improve. Did you read the paper that explains what the parameter does?

When you are choosing the parameter based on the evaluation, then you are cheating. It is an unsupervised method - you are not *supposed* to have such labels in a real use case.

Comment: Actually, when I change `n_neighbors`, `precision`, `recall` and `F1` do not change. There is no improvement. However, `ROC_AUC` does change. Which one is important @Anony-Mousse? `precision`, `recall` and `F1` or `ROC_AUC`

Comment: How do you define precision for a method that outputs a real number? Probably with some threshold. And that is what is nice about ROC - it doesn't depend on your threshold.